# Cannot marshal a struct containing a StringBuilder field

Tags: c#, interop, struct, marshalling, stringbuilder

I need to make interop calls to a DLL written in C++. In the C++ code, there are various functions that receive and return strings. These all use a commonly defined type (struct) in C++, which comprises a pointer to a string along with an integer for its size as follows:

```
struct StringParam
{
    int size;    // 4 byte integer for the size of the string buffer
    LPWSTR buff; // Pointer to a wide char buffer
}
```

When a string is returned from the DLL and when the string buffer is too small to store the string result, an error code is returned along with the correct size buffer that is required in the integer *size* field, so that the caller can provide the right size buffer.

Ignoring the struct for the moment, this could be easily accomplished through interop using the combination of a StringBuilder parameter, along with a ref int parameter for the size. However, we are using a struct and StringBuilder fields are not permitted in structs that are marshalled.

Given a C++ function that receives a string as follows:

```
int __stdcall DoSomethingWithString(StringParam *stringParam)
```

One can declare the following struct in C#:

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
 internal struct StringParam
 {
     public int Size;
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
     public string Text;

     public StringParam(string text)
     {
         this.Text = text;
         this.Size = text.Length;
     }
 }
```

and can successfully initialize a struct and call a C++ function with the following signature:

```
[DllImport("Custom.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int DoSomethignWithString(ref StringParam stringParam);
```

However, given a function that needs to return a string as follows, presents a problem:

```
[DllImport("Custom.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int GetSomeString(ref StringParam stringParam);
```

When receiving a string from the interop call, we do not know the size of the string and must allocate a buffer sufficient in size for storing the string result. StringBuilder would be ideal, but cannot be used within a struct that is marshalled. We could pre-allocate the string with 2048 dummy characters, which could then be used to store the results. This is in fact recommended in the error message one gets when attempting to use the StringBuilder type:

> Cannot marshal field 'Text' of type 'StringParam': Struct or class fields cannot be of type StringBuilder. The same effect can usually be achieved by using a String field and preinitializing it to a string with length matching the length of the appropriate buffer.

This seems kind of messy to pre-initialize a string with dummy values. Is there another/better way to go about this?

Comment: I'd marshal it as IntPtr I think and use manual marshalling

Comment: This struct is already very difficult to use reliably in a C++ program.  There's a nasty memory management problem, it isn't clear who is responsible for releasing the memory for the StringParam.buff member.  Your question doesn't make it clear either.

Comment: The idea was to have an identical struct in C#, which gets declared/allocated in C# first and this gets passed into the C++ API. Thus, the C# app would be responsible for cleaning up.

Comment: Manual marshalling is the way to go here I think. I would create some wrapper method i C# that performs the actual calls and marshalling and simply returns a string. This method of course would free the allocated unmanaged block of memory before returning.